# From a list of (x,y) coordinates how can I find the points where angle changes?

Tags: python, coordinates, tracking, angle

I have a list of (x,y) coordinates that describes a ball's flight through the air. From this list, I want to detect at what points the ball is in contact with the wall, which causes the trajectory of the ball to change.

Is there a way given this list I could find the points around this change of direction?

The track produced by the ball as it travels across the screen and contacts the wall.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any restrictions that must be taken into account, e.g. precision of the tracking? Are you working with some specific libraries? Do you know how to solve this manually, i.e. is your problem finding the algorithm or writing the code?

Comment: Can you share any example of values of `(x, y)`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi To track my list of points contains the centroid coordinates of the ball for every frame of a video. I haven't got any code as I'm not sure how algorithmically speaking how I would go about this problem.

Comment: @mathfux the list of coordinates is stored as the pixels (x,y) position. eg) [(1900,300), (1895,298), (1890, 295), ...] where the 1st pair is for the 1st frame of the video, 2nd for the 2nd frame and so on

Comment: This is more of a generic math or physics question IMO, having little to do with Python.

Comment: @Luke oh, this matters a lot about the code structure. If gaps were not the same, it's more complicated.

Comment: @mathfux yeah the gaps in the points are not uniform, for instance the number of points at the point of contact (angle change) will higher as the ball slows down as it hits the wall.

Comment: @Luke I'm interested not in the gaps in the points but gaps between frames which corresponds to `x` axis. Gap sizes were equal 5 in your example. Can it vary?

Comment: @mathfux for each frame there is a point, as video is at 240fps the frame gap is uniform however as the camera location is not perpendicular to balls horizontal movement the x coordinate doesn't change uniformly. Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems quite easy if we assume there's no air resistance and that impact is elastic. In this case we have a curve formed my two parabolas. Futhermore, double derivatives of these parabolas must be constant in ideal case.

When asking this kind of questions in SO, you really need to add an example of your data, expected output and script examples of what you have tried so far.

I'll use a case where data is

```
data = [(0,-16), (1,-9), (2,-4), (3,-1), (4,-2), (5,-5)]
```

And expected output is 3 since direction of ball changes in `data[3]`

I will also convert this data to a form more convenient to work with:

```
xy = np.array(data)
```

This is an example of situation possible:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [(0,-16), (1,-9), (2,-4), (3,-1), (4,-2), (5,-5)]
xy = np.array(data)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
ax = plt.gca()
X = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
Y = np.linspace(3, 5, 100)
sc1 = ax.scatter(*xy.T, s=25)
sc2 = ax.scatter(X, -(X-4)*(X-4), s=1)
sc3 = ax.scatter(Y, -1-(Y-3)*(Y-3), s=1)
plt.legend([sc1, sc2, sc3], ['frame positions', 'first parabola', 'second parabola'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

We are able to check various properties of this motion:

```
velocity = np.diff(xy[:,1], prepend=np.nan) # [nan  7.  5.  3. -1. -3.]
acceleration = np.diff(velocity, prepend=np.nan) # [nan nan -2. -2. -4. -2.]
acceleration_jumps = np.diff(acceleration, prepend=np.nan) # [nan nan nan  0. -2.  2.]
```

We can see that changes in motion starts between samples `(3,-1), (4,-2)` at index 4. This is a way to track it:

```
rapid_jumps_mask = np.abs(acceleration_jumps)>0 # array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True])
rapid_jump_idx, = np.where(rapid_jumps_mask) # array([4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Finally, sample ids can be tracked with `rapid_jump_idx.tolist()` and it returns `[4,5]`. I expected 3 but it's different because no changes in motion can be observed in samples 0-3.

Since your case is not ideal and also a view is not perpendicular, you may also like to play with different bounds for masking rapid jumps, like so:

```
rapid_jumps_mask = np.abs(acceleration_jumps) > 0.25
```